# ERROR: ipykernel requires Python version 3.4 or above

Tags: python, ipython, atom-editor, hydrogen

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 lts. My default python binary is python2.7. When I am trying to install ipykernel for hydrogen in atom editor, with the following command

```
python -m pip install ipykernel
```

It is giving the following errors

```
ERROR: ipykernel requires Python version 3.4 or above.
```

I am trying to install ipykernel for python2. I have already installed python3.7. Also ipython and jupyter notebook is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with version 5.0 of the [kernel](https://ipykernel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id3), and version 6.0 of [IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version6.html#ipython-6-0), compatibility with Python 2 was dropped.
As far as I know, the only solution is to install an earlier release.

In order to have Python 2.7 available in the Jupyter Notebook I installed IPython 5.7, and ipykernel 4.10. If you want to install earlier releases of IPython or ipykernel you can do the following:

- Uninstall IPython

`pip uninstall ipython`

- Reinstall IPython

`python2 -m pip install ipython==5.7 --user`

- Install ipykernel

`python2 -m pip install ipykernel==4.10 --user`

Comment: the version really matters

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Anaconda`

You can learn how to install Anaconda from [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux.html)

After that, try creating a virtual environment via:

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=2.7 anaconda
```

And activate it via:

```
source activate yourenvname
```

After that, try installing:

```
pip install ipython

pip intall ipykernel
```

Comment: Ok... That is a solution, but I do not want to use virtual environment. Any way the problem is now solved after installing ipython with --user flag. Thanks

Comment: @santanutripathy You are welcome :') However, it is a good practice to use virtual env for your projects. This way if any problem occurs, it won't affect your base env.

Comment: And if you have to use python 3 you can do that without removing python 2.7

Comment: using conda cannot be a solution